# Using decode in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a `DECODE` in my `WHERE` clause like this:

```
Where id = decode('&flag','Yes',(Select id from tab where id > 10),0)
```

This code works if the subquery returns one post. If I returns several I get an error like, ORA-01427, "Single-row subquery returns more than one row"

I've tried to change the '=' to an 'in' but I still get the same error!

Any ideas?

extended example:

```
WHERE Dop_id = (DECODE ('&prep_flag', 'Yes', 
    (SELECT Dop_id FROM 
                   ( SELECT DOP_id, name FROM TABLE)
                    WHERE name IS NOT NULL) 
 , Dop_id))
```

as mention this works if the select statmen returns on row, and not several.

Comment: This is not possible with `=` or with `IN` because `DECODE()` can't return a set as a single result. You'll have to change your design, or use `SELECT MAX(id)...` to limit your set to a single result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming decode is only expecting a single value where you have `Select id from tab where id > 10` I would try moving the select outside of decode:

```
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT decode('&flag', 'Yes', id, 0)
    FROM tab
    WHERE id > 10
)
```

Comment: I can see why i should do it that way you have recomended. But i would like to use the decode on the whare clause. if the flag is Yes then i want all the id where the column name is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Dop_id IN 
      ( CASE &flag
        WHEN 'Yes'
        THEN (SELECT Dop_id 
                FROM TABLE
               WHERE name IS NOT NULL)
        ELSE Dop_id);
```

Comment: i've added an END in the Case clause. But then i've get the same error as before. ORA-01427 (Single-row subquery returns more than one row)